# Error error : "symbol 'grub_calloc' not found

Tags: linux, manjaro

I want install Manjaro instead windows. In general, I want to completely remove Windows and install Linux. Of course, without deleting the personal information I have on Windows, such as images or projects ...
when i restart the system and click on F8 and select USB i getting this error :

```
error: 'grub_calloc' symbol not found.
Entering recovery mode ...
grub rescue>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused. did you install Manjaro or not? You cannot install linux over windows and keep your files, because they are using different file systems. Windows uses NTFS and linux typically uses ext4. You would need to first copy your files from windows to an external drive or cloud service, then put them back once manjaro has been installed.

Regarding the error message, you are probably trying to boot with secure boot enabled. You need to disable this. You can disable this by going into the bios setting. Accessing this depends on your laptop. Finding out how to do this for your laptop can be done using your friend Google. If that doesn't work, your boot loader is probably broken. Google or this [link](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-fix-a-grub-boot-error-symbol-grub_calloc-not-found/) should be able to help